# In a non-inverting op-amp, why is it R1/(R1+R2) instead of R2/(R1+R2) in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

So, why is r1 used in the above formula instead of R2?

Comment: Why would you expect R2 on the top? Explain your thought process. Are you familiar with the equation for a typical resistor divider?

Comment: sadpwner, are you aware that the feedback factor appears in the denominator of the closed-loop gain function (a process of inversion) ?

Comment: The equation is solving for the voltage at the - terminal, *not* Vout (which is where you would see R2 as the numerator).

Answer (score 2):

If I redraw the circuit slightly...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsNABJm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is essentially what is around the OPAMP, a typical voltage divider circuit. V- is the voltage across R1 thus:

\$V- = V_o \frac{R1}{R1+R2}\$

Answer (score 0):

**1. THE VOLTAGE DIVIDER**

If you take two resistors and connect them in series across the terminals of a voltage source (power supply), you'll have something that looks like this:

[image]

Knowing that the current in a series circuit is everywhere the same, and knowing the  values of E1, E3, R1, and R2, we can use Ohm's law to determine the value of the current in the circuit, like this:

$$ It = \frac{E1-E3}{R1+R2} =\frac {10V}{2000\Omega} = \text {0.005 ampere = 5 milliamperes}$$

Then, since we now know the current in the circuit, we can again use Ohm's law to solve for the voltage dropped across R2:

$$ E2 = It R2 = 0.005A \times 1000\Omega = 5\text{ volts.}$$

We can also arrive at the same place in one step by using the less cumbersome voltage divider equation:

$$ E2 = \frac{(E1-E3)R2}{R1+R2} + E3$$

**2. THE NON-INVERTING OPAMP**

In general, the goal of an opamp is to drive its output voltage in whatever direction and to whatever amplitude is required for its + (non-inverting) and - (inverting)  inputs to be at the same voltage.

In the case of this non-inverting amplifier, then, for U1- to be equal to U1+, Vout must swing to +10 in order for E2 to be equal to 5 volts, and for that to happen the product of the opamp's output voltage and the resistance of the resistor connected to the opamp output must be divided bt the sum of the resistances comprising the voltage divider .

[image]